# Videogular not supporting flac audio files

Tags: html, audio, video, html5-audio, videogular

I am using videogular for audio and video player. It is not supporting flac files. I s there any way to run flac files in videogular.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Videogular doesn't have support for flac files.

The best approach is to write a plugin using FLAC.js

[Is there any crossbrowser solution for playing flac? (or is it possible in theory to make one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557049/is-there-any-crossbrowser-solution-for-playing-flac-or-is-it-possible-in-theor)